# How to classify ranges of values in access query

Tags: ms-access

Hello I am currently stuck on a problem. Any help will be appreciated. The data I am looking to classify are weights ranging from 0-80. If the line item is between 0-19 tag it as light 19-39 medium, etc... I am struggling for a starting point for how to get this to work. This query is pulling multiple fields from the data source but this is the only one that is being modified. After this the data will be re-classified based on light, medium, etc.

Thanks for the help. Let me know if anything is needed

Comment: Post some sample data, an example of required output plus any effort you've done so far yourself.

Comment: You can use nested iifs or a switch statement

Comment: Here is what I have I tried a switch but it didn't work

Switch(
SteelData.[Unit Weight] <19.0001,Light,
SteelData.[Unit Weight] >19.0001 and < 39.00001, Medium,
SteelData.[Unit Weight] >39.0001 and < 79.00001, Heavy,
SteelData.[Unit Weight] >79.0001 and < 119.00001, Extra Heavy,
SteelData.[Unit Weight] >119.0001 and < 394.00001, Extra Extra Heavy,
SteelData.[Unit Weight] >394.0001, Extra Jumbo
) As Classification

Comment: I want the output of the Query to look like this

Classification                 Unit Weight             Length
      Light                                15                       10
      Medium                           25                      56

Answer (score 3):

You can make a table called `WeightClasses`

[image]

Then you can join to this

```
Select t.*, wc.weightclassname
From Things as t
inner join WeightClasses as wc 
    on t.Weight >= wc.LowerBound and t.Weight < wc.UpperBound
```

This will produce results like this

[image]

I think this is a lot easier to read and auditable than `IIF` statements. You can change your classifications in a table without changing code and you can make sense of your classes very quickly and easily by looking at the table. You can also add weight classes just by adding new records.

Answer (score 0):

USE IIF like this:

> IIF(SteelData.[Unit Weight]<19.0001,'Light',IIF(SteelData.[Unit Weight] <
>   39.00001,'Medium',IIF([etc.])))