# Interval Range of values

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

[after a question that I put before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379532/right-join-and-inner-join-in-the-same-access-query), I need to create ranges of DAP values for differents 'EspCodigo'. See table.

### Previous result:

```
InvntID EspCodigo   DAP   Objectivo 
15      Ec          15    Rolaria_Ec
16      Ec          5     Rolaria_Ec
26      Pb          50    Folha_Pb  
27      Pb          20    Lenha_Pb  
28      Ec          12    Rolaria_Ec
29      Ec          30    Rolaria_Ec
30      Ec          5     Rolaria_Ec
31      Ec          7     Rolaria_Ec
32      Ec          40    Desenrolar_Ec
```

I had use the function Partition but it presents not so good result like example:

```
Range: Partition([DAP];0;250;5)
```

```
 Range      Count    EspCodigo
  0:  4     32        EC
  5:  9     294       EC
 10: 14     673       EC
 15: 19     521       ...
 20: 24     421       ...
 25: 29     288       ...
 30: 34     199       ...
```

### The answer should be:

The ranges are not: >0 to <5, >=5 to <10, >=10 to <15, >=15 to <20, ... How can I make like this?

Thanks,

Comment: I don't know about this specific Access funtion, but there's a similar one in Standard SQL and this allows switching the ranges, i.e. `Partition([DAP];250;0;5)` which might result in your logic

Comment: In standard SQL? Which function? [In python is possible to use bin function](https://www.python-course.eu/pandas_python_binning.php).

Comment: It's `width_bucket` https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sql-in-a/9780596155322/re91.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure in Access you will be able to define an additional query over the top of the existing query (the one which has the Partition function) and apply a formula to transform the Range column to the presentation format you want i.e. set a formula over the Range column to something like:

```
=">" & Replace(Range, ": ", " to <=")
```

i.e. you want to prefix each Range value with ">" and then replace the ": " with " to <=".

Comment: Hello, I try to use it and is not what I want. Result: "> 0 to <=4". Even when I have intervals to create from 3 digits it doesn't make the correction.

Comment: It would help if you could share the text of the SQL queries you are using. Otherwise it's difficult to understand precisely where your issues may be coming from.